# Imacros Search AND Replace

Tags: html, imacros

Is there a way to find and replace text Imacros box fields.
only need **771309** export and input fields.

> test.com/Se/JpegImage.aspx?CapVal=771309

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear. Is this what you need?

```
SET CapVal EVAL("'{{!URLCURRENT}}'.split('CapVal=')[1];")
PROMPT {{CapVal}}
```

Comment: send email for . need extract 771309 and add to form.